# How to fix code to remove formulas but leave values in all sheets APART from those specified

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, google-sheets

I want to remove formulas and paste values in all sheets apart from `Base Data` and `Template`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    if(
      (sheet.getSheetName() == "Base Data") || 
      (sheet.getSheetName() == "Template")  
    );
    function removeFormulas() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
        .forEach(function (sh) {
          var r = sh.getDataRange()
          r.copyTo(r, {
            contentsOnly: true
          })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The desired outcome would be to leave the formulas in `Base Data` and `Template` alone but for the other tabs to have them removed and the values maintained.

Comment: OK. Quick response = quick question - What;'s wrong with the code that is in your question?

Comment: When I run the code one of 2 things happen. Firstly, the script appears to be running but upon completion it leaves the formulas in all the sheets. Secondly - the script runs and removes the formulas but leaves the values in ALL sheets even the ones I've specified it to ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested - but it might give some idea.

The main difference is to test for sheet names NOT equal to your listed sheets, then everything other sheet should have copy, contents only.

---

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    if(sheet.getSheetName() != "Base Data" || sheet.getSheetName() != "Template") {

            var thissheet = ss.getSheetbyName(sheet.getSheetName());
            var lR = thissheet.getLastRow();
            var LC = thissheet.getLastColumn();
            var range = thissheet.getRange(1,1,LR,LC);
            range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});

        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** 
The following script has been tested and runs as per the OP's expectations. Sheets "Base Data" and "Template" are excluded from the `copyTo` method.

There are a few things to note:

- The `if` statement combines the test for "Base Data" and "Template" with an **AND** rather than an OR. The required logic is to establish that the current sheet name is neither of the named sheets. AND has the effect of treating this as a whole; OR has the effect of allowing one or the other to be true, but doesn't enforce the condition of them both being true.
- I made a mistake by including `getSheetbyName()`. This was unnecessary because the loop has already created the context for the sheet.

---

```
function so5850593801() {

  // setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get all the sheets
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

  // loop through the sheets
  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    var sheetname = sheet.getSheetName();

    // don't process Base data or Template
    if(sheetname !== "Base Data" &&  sheetname !== "Template") {
      var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
      var LC = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,LR,LC);
      range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation. I've used the code and got the error message below.

TypeError: ss.getSheetbyName is not a function (line 8, file "Absolute")

any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Line 1 change to`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

Comment: Amended the first line, however i'm still getting the error message.

Comment: Amended this line below to capitalise the B to remove the error mentioned above.

var thissheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet.getSheetName());

The script runs and correctly pastes values. However it is still including "Template" and "Base Data" and not excluding them

Comment: Refer the Update - the code is working and skips the "Base Data" and "Template" sheets.